# Use different colors depending on the number of series - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to figure out how to use create a bit of logic that will apply different color palettes for my highcharts graphs, depending on how many series are in the graph.

For example, say I want to use this palette if the graph has 4 lines:

```
 colors: ['#000', '#333', '#666', #999]
```

but I want to use this palette if the graph has 2 lines:

```
 colors: ['#000', '#666']
```

How can I achieve this kind of conditional coloring in Highcharts? Perhaps these might help:

- Can I use a function as the value of the `colors` property?
- How do I get the number of series in a graph?

Answer (score 1):

jsfiddle is down ATM but I believe something like the following should work which I adapted from the [basic line demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) on the highcharts website.

```
var chart;
var options={
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
};
$(document).ready(function() {  
    loadChart();
});

function loadChart(){
    var colors=[];
    var seriesCount=option.series.length;
    if(seriesCount == 2){
        colors=['#000', '#666'];
    }else if(seriesCount == 3){
        colors=['#000', '#333', '#666'];
    }else if(seriesCount == 4){
        colors=['#000', '#333', '#666', #999];
    }
    for(var i=0;i<seriesCount;i++){
        options.series[i].color=colors[i];
    }
    chart= new Highcharts.Chart(options);
}
```